# Loading ressources from evernote with nodejs

Tags: node.js, stream, evernote

I am fighting with currently with nodejs, trying to download images from evernote via the api.

```
noteStore.getResourceData(guid, function (err, res) {
    console.log(res.length);
});
```

my problem with this code is, in my console I can see the the length of the file, but as soon I try to use the value somewhere else, or save the file, I hit problems.

```
var l = res.length;
           ^
```

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

any ideas how to fix this?

What I wont is to save the file, but I hitting the same problem when I use this:

```
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(guid + '.' + type);
wstream.write(res);
```

Comment: you are not looking on err variable- there might be some problem with getting the resource and there for res is not defined. check if the err variable is defined

Comment: @NirLevy as I said, I can console.log the length and I will get a value, and the next row with var l = res.length will throw an error

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so far there is no solution for this in the internet, I found a way to handle the image download and saving:

```
noteStore.getResourceData(guid, function (err, res) {
            try{
                var buffer = new Buffer(res);

                var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(guid + '.' + type, {'flags': 'w', encoding: 'binary'});
                wstream.write(buffer, encoding='binary', function(err) {

                });

            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
});
```